# Bootstrap table and AngularJS (dymanic content)

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a [Boostrap table](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/index.html) with and edit and delete button inside each row.
I created a AngularJS controller and generating the table using a AngularJS directive.

Used libraries:

- Bootstrap 3
- Bootstrap Table
- AngularJS

Here is my JS code:

```
(function () {
    // angular applciation 
    var app = angular.module('micro-operacao-list-app', []);

    // angular directive to configure Bootstrap table via JS
    app.directive('initTable', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',

            link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
                var opts = scope.$eval(attrs.initTable);

                el.bootstrapTable(opts);

            }

        };
    });

    // Table controller (configuration and actions)
    app.controller('GridController', function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.options = {
            method: 'get',
            url: Utils.getContext() + '/microoperacao/rest',
            queryParams: function(pageSize, pageNumber, searchText) {
                return {
                    start: pageSize * (pageNumber-1),
                    length: pageSize
                };
            },
            pagination: true,
            sidePagination: 'server',

            height: 'auto',
            striped: true,
            pageSize: 10,
            pageList: [10, 25, 50, 100],
            search: false,
            showColumns: true,
            columns: [{
                field: 'id',
                title: 'Código',
                align: 'right',
                valign: 'middle',
                width: 100,
                sortable: false
            }, {
                field: 'descricao',
                title: 'Descrição',
                align: 'left',
                valign: 'middle',
                sortable: false
            }, {
                title: 'Ações',
                width: 75,
                formatter: function(value, row, index) {

                    // //////////////////////////
                    // CREATION OF BUTTONS FOR EDIT AND DELETE RECORDS
                    // //////////////////////////

                    return '<a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="list.btnEditarClick(' + row.id + ')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>&nbsp; ' +
                    '<a class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>';
                }
            }]
        };

    });

    // controller for new and edit records
    app.controller('ListController', ['$window', function($window) {

        this.btnNovoClick = function() {
            $window.location.href = Utils.getContext() + '/microoperacao/novo';
        };

        this.btnEditarClick = function(id) {
            $window.location.href = Utils.getContext() + '/microoperacao/' + id;
        };

    }]);

})();
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container-fulid" ng-app="micro-operacao-list-app">
    <div ng-controller="ListController as list">
        <p>
            <a ng-click="list.btnNovoClick()" target="_self" class="btn btn-default btn-primary btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Novo</a>
        </p>

        <div ng-controller="GridController as ctrl">
            <table init-table="options">
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This results in:

[image]

**The problem**

Each line has an edit button (see image), and each button has the

```
ng-click="list.btnEditClick({id})"
```

This is generated via **GridController**.

When I click the edit button, nothing occurrs. Seems that the "ng-click" has no action.

Why? What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: After a few minutes "googling", I found the $compile method. Can this be the solution? Recompile the table element to process the ng-click attribute after load the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I found that I need to "recompile" the dom of my table with AngularJS, to process the custom format elements generated by the load data process.

Here is the code:

```
app.directive('initTable', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
            var opts = scope.$eval(attrs.initTable);

            opts.onLoadSuccess = function() {
                $compile(el.contents())(scope); 
            };

            el.bootstrapTable(opts);
        }

    };
}]);
```

I inject the **onLoadSuccess** (bootstrap table event) to fire the recompilation of the dom after the table load.

Comment: and what about when you dont have a directive?

Comment: I can assume that it will work, but what about the performance? it doesn't seem that good (in theory as you would be recompiling all the time). Definitely the efficient way would be to create a ngBootstrapTable component adapted to angular way. Note that you can use ng-grid from angular-ui suite

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, It was my solution:

In the bootstrap-table-angular.js external file, I added the $compile parameter to the directive, as like:

```
 angular.module('bsTable', [])
        .constant('uiBsTables', {bsTables: {}})
        .directive('bsTableControl', ['uiBsTables', '$compile', function (uiBsTables,$compile) { .... }
```

then, Inside directive, I added code to compile the content element when the table finishes loading, as like:

```
 $el.bind('post-body.bs.table', function() {
       $compile($el.contents())($s);
  });
```

Finally, inside of my string html code I added the "$parent" beafore the function:

```
  formatter: function getActions (value, row, index){
        return '<button ng-click="$parent.edit('+row+')" class="btn btn-default">Edit</button>';                                
    }
```

This changes were sufficient to me. 
I used the next link: [bootstrap-table-angular](http://plnkr.co/edit/MyeotRj4YMR0zpofm8lf?p=preview) try check it.

Answer (score -1):

A couple things seem to be wrong.  First, you don't need to assign the ng-click function as a property to an object like list.btnEditClick(). Secondly, you should pass the object as the parameter rather than the id.

Created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zjU8A/

```
var app = angular.module('listApp',[]);

app.controller('ListCtrl',function($scope) {
   $scope.list = [{id:'92',desc:'Test1'},{id:'93',desc:'Test2'}];

   $scope.editListItem = function(item) {
       alert(item.desc);
   };
});
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to edit the object at the "click", I want to redirect to another page. The edition is more detailed than the listing.

Comment: The alert was just an example of what you can do with the object once the ng-click function was called.  For redirects, you can use $location.path('edit/' + $scope.items.indexOf(item)); or whatever you're trying to implement.

Comment: Yes, I know it! But the problem is, the ng-click has no action... seems the resulting html in the table formatter isn't been processed.

Comment: ng-click="list.btnEditClick({id})" should be ng-click="btnEditClick({id})"

Comment: @Rob , you jsfiddle link does not work anymore.  Can you update it?